# Trying to create docker image with bash script

Tags: linux, bash, docker, dockerfile

I want to create docker images using next script

```
docker build - < $2 -t $1
```

the first parameter is the image name, second is the path to Dockerfile.

I have the next file structure for it.

[image]

I'm getting error on COPY method

```
No such file or directory
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM postgres
WORKDIR ./bacisImage
ENV POSTGRES_DB pointer
ENV POSTGRES_PASSWORD pointer
ENV POSTGRES_DB 123
COPY migrations/tables/* /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
COPY migrations/procedures/* /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
```

Comment: please share the `Dockerfile` or at least the output of `grep -E '(ADD|COPY)' Dockerfile` in case you have secret variables and the sort

Comment: nvm. got it. you were almost there in your supposition of workir. `docker build` relies on the [**context**](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#:~:text=The%20docker%20build%20command%20builds,a%20file%20in%20the%20context.). so the default context was `./` which doesn't match the one you expected

Comment: Please [don’t post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: Shell error clearly says what's the mistake here. It can't file the source files to copy.  `migrations` for example isn't directly under `resource/docker`. It should be `basicImage/migrations/tables/*`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rather than the path to a Dockerfile, use either `basicImage` or `dataImage` -- the **directories** which hold the Dockerfiles.

and modify your script to use the path to the **folder** containing your Dockerfile

```bash
# ...
docker build -t $1 $2
# ...
```

from the [docker-build docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/)
the syntax for the build command is

```
$ docker build [OPTIONS] PATH | URL | -
```

`PATH` here is what provides the build command its [**context**](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#:%7E:text=The%20docker%20build%20command%20builds,a%20file%20in%20the%20context.)

> A build’s context is the set of files located in the specified `PATH` or `URL`. The build process can refer to any of the files in the context. For example, your build can use a COPY instruction to reference a file in the context.

what you pass via `-` (stdin) is the Dockerfile, which only provides the instructions. with `PATH` being absent, the default context is `./`

so the Dockerfile is trying to copy `migrations/tables`. but the context of `./` has only `basicImage` and `dataImage`; hence the COPY fails.

if instead you pass the `PATH` of `basicImage`, that is the new context. and the file Dockerfile within the context is used for building the image and everything would work as expected

Comment: I fixed by providing PATH to folder, but not Dockerfile

Comment: hi. thanks. i've edited my answer to clarify my intent better :)